# List in a List?

Tags: list, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I need to create a generic list that contains list of gameobjects in Unity.

```js
var gameObjectList:List.<List.<GameObject>> = new List.<List.<GameObject>>();
```

but I am getting errors about the syntax. I rather not use an Array which I have to type-cast. Can anybody point me to the right direction?

Comment: Next time please do include the exact error messages you get. For something non-trivial they are quite helpful when it comes to locating and solving your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a simple matter of spaces. One of the first errors you get (and it will get worse after that) is something like:

> BCE0044: expecting >, found '>>'.

Change the line to

```js
var gameObjectList:List.< List.<GameObject> > = new List.< List.<GameObject> >();
```

and all should be well.